# Keep ID in URL on multiple form failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right, so `http://localhost:3000/reviews/new/5` tells my app to set up a product review for product with ID 5. However, when I submit the form with bogus information I trigger this code in the 'create' action:

```
    @style = Style.find(params[:review][:style_id])
    render 'new'
```

When the page reloads I get the new URL `http://localhost:3000/reviews` which is fine, but if I submit bogus info AGAIN, then on the next page load @style fails to be assigned.

This is the code in the 'new' action:

```
    @style = Style.find(params[:id])
    @review = current_user.reviews.build(style_id: params[:id])
```

I'm sure this is simple. Breaking for dinner.

I fixed it by adding an if statement to my view... I changed:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :style_id, :value => params[:id] %>
```

to:

```
<% if params[:id] == nil %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :style_id, :value => params[:review][:style_id] %>
<% else %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :style_id, :value => params[:id] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Add a hidden field to your form that holds the `style_id`.

Comment: Sorry, I have one already. That's how     @style = Style.find(params[:review][:style_id]) works

Comment: Well, show the code for the hidden field. You are doing something wrong there.

Comment: You're welcome. See my answer for the solution to your problem ;-)

Comment: Oh you solved it already, but you don't need the if statement. Just use `@style.id` to set the value in the hidden field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
<% if params[:id] == nil %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :style_id, :value => params[:review][:style_id] %>
<% else %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :style_id, :value => params[:id] %>
<% end %>
```

You could simply do this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :style_id, :value => @style.id %>
```

Comment: And to avoid an error when @style is nil, <%= f.hidden_field :style_id, :value => @style.try(:id) %>